# Python and FPDF email attachment FPDF error: Not a PNG file

Tags: python, file, fpdf, bytesio

I'm trying to make a PDF on the fly in my app. I recently ported a Python 2 code to Python 3. And now, it fails with `FPDF error: Not a PNG file: /tmp/tmpoi0oz__u` at this line

```py
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', buffering=1) as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(signature_data))
    self.image(f.name, type='PNG', h=40) # Fails here (says this is not a PNG).
    ...
```

**The code:**

```py
...
    try:
        from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin
        from io import BytesIO
        import tempfile
        html = """
        <img src="{}/static/media/logo.png" height="25">
        """.format(script_dir)

        class PDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
            def footer(self):
                if signature_data:
                    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', buffering=1) as f:
                        f.write(base64.b64decode(signature_data))
                        self.image(f.name, type='PNG', h=40)
                        self.cell(0, 10, 'Signed on: {}'.format(timestamp), 0, 1, 'L')
                else:
                    self.cell(0, 10, 'No valid signature was found. Please contact us for a new form.', 0, 1, 'C')
                self.set_y(-15)
                self.cell(0, 10, 'Page ' + str(self.page_no()) + '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C')

        pdf = PDF()
        pdf.alias_nb_pages()
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 12)
        pdf.write_html(html)
        tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
        with open(tf.name, "w", encoding='utf-8',
                 errors='ignore') as f:
            pdf.output(f.name, dest='F')
            attachment = f.name
        send_mail(subject="Your PDF", message=message, 
            bcc_mail="myemail@gmail.com", attachment=attachment)
    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        print("PDF FAIL")
...
```

**Traceback:**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "registration.py", line 233, in send_mail_with_pdf
    pdf.output(f.name, dest='F')
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1065, in output
    self.close()
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 241, in close
    self.footer()
  File "registration.py", line 218, in footer
    self.image(f.name, type='PNG', h=40)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 150, in wrapper
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 971, in image
    info=self._parsepng(name)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1780, in _parsepng
    self.error('Not a PNG file: '+name)
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 227, in error
    raise RuntimeError('FPDF error: '+msg)
RuntimeError: FPDF error: Not a PNG file: /tmp/tmpoi0oz__u
 PDF FAIL
 FPDF error: Not a PNG file: /tmp/tmpoi0oz__u
```

I have tried finding the issue for hours now and I am unable to proceed. Please help.

Comment: Using Python 3.x you have to use [`pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1')`](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/output/index.html)

Comment: I used this code, but I still get `FPDF error: Not a PNG file:` at this line `self.image(f.name, type='PNG', h=40)`.

Comment: Your whole`if signature_data:` code block looks wrong? You want to add a signature which seems to be a `PNG` file or do you want to insert `signature_data`? Explain what is `signature_data`?

Comment: Outdent this statement, `self.image(f.name ...` to force the opened file to flush the buffer and close the file.

Comment: @stovfl, `signature_data` is a base64 encoded image of a signature. Example - https://pastebin.com/raw/UPjk4BR8. I will try the flush option and report back.

Comment: @stovfl, I outdented it and tried it, this time I get a `File not found` error. Traceback is here - https://pastebin.com/raw/DCp6efBN .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212163/discussion-between-stovfl-and-claudia).